# Join tables on json object in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, join

I have two tables each with 3 columns and I need to join these tables on product_type. How I can do this?

```
table1 has columns 
  category(varchar), subcategory(varchar), product_type(json) 

table2 has columns 
  product_type(varchar), brand(varchar), attribute(json)

product_type(json) has list of product_type.
```

How can i do this??
I am trying like this:

```
select subcategory, a.product_type, brand, attribute
from table1 as a, table2 as b
where a.product_type::text = b.product_type and category = "bike";
```

Comment: How is `product_type` structured? Is that a json array or a list of key-values?